# resignFirstResponder only if all textFields are filled

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I want to `resignFirstResponder()` for one `textField` only if all `textFields` are filled. However for some reason it doesn't work. No matter if others are filled, it only checks for the one responder one.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
//Check wheather fields are filled or not and then enable or disable register button
    func textChanged(_ sender: NSNotification) {
        if usernameField.hasText && emailField.hasText && passwordField.hasText && confirmPasswordField.hasText {
            registerButton.isEnabled = true
            confirmPasswordField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        else {
            registerButton.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
```

And I also tried:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
        if usernameField.hasText && emailField.hasText && passwordField.hasText && confirmPasswordField.hasText {
        confirmPasswordField.resignFirstResponder()
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The code is fine. I just tried and it works. I am not sure I understood what you meant by "No matter if others are filled, it only checks for the one responder one." Do you mean to say that the resignFirstResponder triggers only when focussed on confirmPasswordField?

Comment: I have 4 fields and I want the last field to be firstresponder only if all others are filled also.

Comment: OK. What's wrong now? What happens if you have text in textfields 1,2, 3 and hit return before entering data into 4? What happens if you press return after entering data in 4?

Comment: if 4th is empty the button is disabled and if 4th is filled the button is enabled. If I press "return" which is actually Done in my case, it triggers user registration.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I used

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if text1.hasText() && text2.hasText() && text3.hasText() && text4.hasText(){
        registerButton.enabled = true
        text4.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

I am not sure how you are calling the textChanged function so I can't really figure out what you are trying to do there.

If you want to ensure that a user cannot move to text4 before filling out text1, text2, text3 then use another `if` block to implement that.